# Processing text and resetting in requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Decided to go with Python-requests to write a REST client. All works well for POSTs, however all isn't quite going as well on GETs.

The REST server prepends `throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';` to all GET responses(as an anti-phishing mechanism). Which was easy enough to remove using the standard python regex library, using the following statement: `re.sub('\A.*[;]\n', "", r.text)`(might not be perfect, but gets the job done). (Assume r is the response data structure)

However, the problem occurs when I go to reset the post-processed text back to r.text with: `r.text = re.sub('\A.*[;]\n', "", r.text)` which throws the following Exception:`AttributeError: can't set attribute`, which would make me believe text is a read-only field. (I would like to reset the text field, so I could use the json functionality of the Response object)

So now that I have the background problem layed out, I guess my question is does anybody know a solution as well as why text is a read-only attribute? (Note, I am aware that I could just go in and add a setter for the text attribute in the actual requests source, but would prefer not to for many reasons (don't want to break the build on future releases, portability, etc)).

Comment: `.text` is a *property*; it provides the decoded results of the response. Not that you need to alter it; you are going about this the wrong way, really.

Comment: I know that I don't *need* to, but I feel like abstracting away the stripping and then treating it like any other response is more elegant than going about handling it entirely differently than I would other responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to set the `text` attribute again, if all you want to do is decode JSON:

```
import json

json.loads(re.sub('\A.*[;]\n', "", r.text))
```

If you have a burning need to fix the response body, set `response._content` instead; read it from the `.content` property first:

```
r._content = re.sub('\A.*[;]\n', "", r.content)
```